# How can I show a view controller on the first launch only in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just want to show an operator screen  with three operators on the first time when app launches and if i did not selected any operator and i closed the app and again when i open the app i should see that operator screen only but i am going to home view controller. This is my code:

Home ViewController.m

```
if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            objectForKey:@"aValue"]])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"aValue"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //Action here

    UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Operator"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];


}
 else
 {
 //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


 }
```

Any changes to my code so that i can get the desired result. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Your code looks correct. Your navigationController might however be nill

Comment: On the very first time operator screen is coming and if selected any one of the operators no problem, if i did not selected any operator and i closed my app and again opened it, i am redirecting to home screen rather i need to show the operator screen only until i selected any one of that.

Comment: ah OK. You need to wait calling
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"aValue"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Till you have selected the operator

Comment: How can i set that any code help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"aValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

should be moved into the view controller in which the user selects the operator. This should be done after the operator is selected and just before dismissing the operator view controller.